# Why using jQuery's .html() to create a node from html doesn't work?

Tags: jquery

I'm at a loss.

.html() returns a string, and

```
$( "<div></div>" )
```

creates a node from html.

So can anyone explain me why the following will return an error message ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $( document ).ready(
                function() {
                    var html = $( "ul.menu" ).html();
                    var test = $( html );
                }
            );
        </script>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="">Button 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Button 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Button 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Button 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Button 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the error message ? It looks fine.

Comment: Yes, it does look fine. The error message is :Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <li><a href="">...

Comment: I've made a fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/LYyX2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NG9ha/ explained by @DocKuro answer

Answer (score 1):

Well, with

```
var html = $( "ul.menu" ).html();
```

you will get all the li's in your menu, but when you wrap it in jquery you don't have a single element, but all of them!

Try to cycle through every `<li>` and do what you need on the single elements

Look this fiddle for some start line to cycle the li collection: http://jsfiddle.net/Ge22N/1/

If you want to add a li node to the ul instead, look this: http://jsfiddle.net/Ge22N/3/

Comment: If I wrap the above html var in jquery I don't get all the elements, but an error message : http://jsfiddle.net/LYyX2/

Comment: As I said, that's because you are trying to wrap multiple elements' html inside the jQuery and that's bad. Try to explain what you would like to achieve and maybe I can give you some more insight.

Answer (score 0):

if you are expecting `var test` to be the entire `<ul>` you should do something like this:

```
var html = $( "ul.menu" ).html();
var test = $("<ul />", { html: html );
```

See also [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGmTa/):

**EDIT:**

I think you have a point indeed. I checked [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LYyX2/) and changed it into a piece of html without linebreaks ([see here](http://jsfiddle.net/LYyX2/1/)). If there are no line breaks in the HTML your code works perfectly. Probably jQuery cannot create nodes when linebreaks exist in the HTML string.

Comment: I was expecting the var test to contain the <li> nodes.